# Instagram creates a new "Camera" folder, how do I deal with it?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, camera, gallery, instagram

I'm on Android 2.3.4, Xperia Active. And I have downloaded and installed Instagram.

Normally when I take pictures on the stock Camera app, my photos gets sent to **sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO**. However, when I installed Instagram and started to use it, I notice that it created a new folder under **sdcard/DCIM** and called it **Camera** and that is where it places the pictures I take inside the app. What's worse is that, aside from creating the **sdcard/DCIM/Camera** folder, it also creates the same image inside **sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO**. So whenever I take an Instagram photo, that picture gets 2 copies plus the third one with the applied filters on a separate folder called **Instagram**.

This may not have been an issue because I can always clear the **sdcard/DCIM/Camera** folder every after some time. But the thing is, it's showing up on my Gallery app as two Camera folders.

[image: The top one is the one default used by the Camera app and the bottom one is created by Instagram.]

I *thought* I fixed it when I placed a .nomedia file inside the Instagram-created **Camera** folder. Sure, after I force reload the Gallery app, it will hide **sdcard/DCIM/Camera** then. But when I take another photo on Instagram, it resurfaces on the Gallery app again. This time, it only shows the latest taken picture as viewable. And the old contents are shown as broken images (see the one hilited in yellow below).

[image]

Sure enough when I force reload the Gallery app, it hides again but I don't want to have to force reload it each and every time. I know that this is just a simple problem for some but I'm really not too pleased to see duplicates of the same image showing up.

I'm really sorry for the lengthy post but I'm not sure how to describe my problem so I tried to put in as much detail as I can. If you need more info, please say so and I'll gladly add it.

So in essence, the questions are:

- How do I permanently hide the unnecessary Camera folder that Instagram created?
- Is there a way to make Instagram just use default **100ANDRO** folder instead of creating a new **Camera** one AND creating a duplicate on the default folder?

Again, sorry if this seems all confusing, please try to bear it with me.

Comment: Are you sure both are identical photos. I suppose, one is original & another is with instagram effect.

Comment: No. The one with Instagram filters applied are placed inside it's respective Instagram folder inside the Pictures folder I think. The image Instagram creates on 100ANDRO and Camera are the same. They only have different file names.

Answer (score 2):

Use an app like [gallery excluder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mrfloppycoding.galleryexcluder&hl=en). Alternatively you could do it manually.

in the folder that you want to exclude create an empty file and name it .nomedia than you need to delete the media scanner database. Go to:

```
Settings -> Apllications -> All -> Media Storage -> Clear Data
```

Now reboot your phone. It might take a while for your pictures to appear again but these instagram folders will not be there.

Instagram unfortunately doesn't have an option to choose a folder for saving pictures.

---

If the above doesn't work or if you want a really cool gallery app try [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en).

Comment: Just tried this now. It again showed the Camera folder on the Gallery app after I snapped a picture inside Instagram. The only difference is that now, I don't see the broken images on my example above. But the problem still remains where the unnecessary Camera folder is visible. :(

Comment: I'm puzzled than. I did this several times before and it always worked. The only reason I can see as to why it doesn't work is that 'DCIM/Camera' is supposed to be the the standard camera folder so the gallery might ignore the '.nomedia' because of that. You could try using Quickpic which is a far superior gallery app and it supports hiding folders without .nomedia.

Comment: I already have QuickPic though. I use it for viewing GIFs. However, I wanted to keep the Gallery app for aesthetic purposes. If DCIM/Camera is the standard folder, how come the Camera app saves it to 100ANDRO?

Comment: It's because of Sony's customizations. AOSP devices and roms based on that save it to camera.

Comment: So is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mrfloppycoding.galleryexcluder&hl=en

Comment: Saving to 100ANDRO actually makes a bit more sense than saving to Camera. The [DCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system) standard says the folder a digital camera stores its images on must be called a name matching "100ABCDE" and you can't actually expect any application to be able to find and import your photos if it is called any other way. In practice it might work anyway with some programs.

Comment: @Erik most programs scan the whole DCIM folder including all sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you format your SD card with the EXT2 file system you can create a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from `Camera` to `100ANDRO`. If you do this, any app that tries to read or write to `Camera` will be redirected to `100ANDRO`. To do this, you will need a PC running Linux, OSX or another Unix. As I don't have one available, I unfortunately cannot give you any exact instructions.

Note that you won't be able to mount your phone in MSC mode on Windows if you do this. Also, I'm not 100% sure that Gingerbread does support EXT-formatted SD cards.

Comment: It would still show up as two folders.

Comment: Yes, but this would make Instagram use the default folder. He'd still have to use Gallery Exclude to hide the other one.

Comment: Gallery excluder adds a .nomedia file inside the folder so it would hide both.